# What are the minimal guidelines for a dual command-line / gui interface?

Tags: forms, command-line

I'm designing a website that has a constant CLI and optional GUI's for every functionality. What i'm basically doing is an automated form generated for each parameter and a description.

I'm also indicating with a red asterisk the required parameters.

It works pretty much like this:
cmd is a generic command. visual is a command that makes the form for the command:

> visual cmd

Then it makes something like this:
[image: Sample]

That's all i have, can you point me to improvements on this subject?

My goal: The system is mainly for the cli, so i want to drive users to it. This autoform thing should be a transition/helper, what else should i add?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Right now your question doesn't sound constructive.

Comment: What am i missing? The visual mode is for beginners.

Comment: "What else should I add?" and "Can you point me to improvements on this subject?" are very vague questions. It's unclear what the workflow is and whether users stumble in it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that CLI systems have been doing similar things for years:
1) help (cmd)
and 2) (cmd) /?

have both been used in OS like DOS and VMS.  Asking (presumably novice) users to learn a new command to get help seems counter-intuitive.  While not as pretty as your solution, those systems have been effective in providing help.

Unless your command line interface is significantly more complex than what you have presented, perhaps you have a solution in search of a problem.